# How to group by specific month of year in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Here is a collection:

```
{
    _id: "",
    name: "",
    date: ""
}
```

I use this code for group by year:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            year: {
                $year: '$date'
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Now I want to group by a specific month of that year. for example group by the 2nd month of every year.
Here is an example:

```
{
    _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f3689",
    name: "black",
    date: ISODate("2016-04-24T11:42:00.000Z")
},
{
    _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f0679",
    name: "blue",
    date: ISODate("2017-03-15T11:42:00.000Z")
},
{
    _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f0689",
    name: "red",
    date: ISODate("2017-04-12T11:42:00.000Z")
},
{
    _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f0479",
    name: "green",
    date: ISODate("2017-04-15T11:42:00.000Z")
},
{
    _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f0379",
    name: "yellow",
    date: ISODate("2018-03-04T11:42:00.000Z")
}
```

This is the output I want:

```
[
    {
        _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f3689",
        name: "black",
        date: ISODate("2016-04-24T11:42:00.000Z")
    },
    {
        _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f0679",
        name: "blue",
        date: ISODate("2017-03-15T11:42:00.000Z")
    }
]
[
    {
        _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f0689",
        name: "red",
        date: ISODate("2017-04-12T11:42:00.000Z")
    },
    {
        _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f0479",
        name: "green",
        date: ISODate("2017-04-15T11:42:00.000Z")
    },
    {
        _id: "5a913bc6497a433de83f0379",
        name: "yellow",
        date: ISODate("2018-03-04T11:42:00.000Z")
    }
]
```

Grouped by 4th month of every year 'till the 3rd month of the next year.

Comment: can you post expected output with some sample documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$month](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/index.html) to get month from date (returns number from 1 to 12). If you want to group all documents specifying year threshold as a particular month you can use following aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { y: { $year: "$date" }, m: { $month: "$date" } },
                    in: { $cond: { if: { $gte: [ "$$m", 4 ] }, then: "$$y", else: { $subtract: [ "$$y", 1 ] } } }
                }
            },
            docs: {
                $push: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically if month is greater than or equal than `4` (in this case) then it's current year and it's previous otherwise.

Comment: This doesn't work, I want to group for example from January 2016 To January 2017, or February 2017 To February 2018

Comment: @WithoutBrain1994 now I get it, modified my answer